# Algorithm for random selection of a number and a multiplier depending on range

Tags: algorithm, math

I have 3 arrays (values may vary)

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 15];
$multipliers = [1, 2, 3];
$range = [0, 10];
```

I need an algorithm that can randomly get a value that is within `$range` using a random element from `$numbers` and from `$multipliers`.
For example, it randomly takes `​​2` from `$numbers` and `3` from `$multipliers`, it turns out 2 * 3 = 6 which is between `$range` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive solution is to simply pick `x` from `$numbers`, `y` from `$multipliers`, compute `z=x*y` and return it if it's in range. If not, simply start again. This solution could run for a very long time, depending on the numbers and range. One possible improvement is to precompute, for each element in `numbers`, which range of values in `multipliers` is a valid candidate to be within `range`. If you sort the arrays in `O(n logn)`, you can compute the valid range for each number using a binary search on the second array (finding the upper and lower bounds) for each element in the first. This still gives you a time of `O(n logn)`. Then simply pick one element from the first array uniform at random, and one from the second array in the desired range also uniform at random, multiply and return.